# ¿En que podría estar fallando? On first connect MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, centos

Quería formular esta pregunta, ya que estoy recibiendo este error al intentar conectarme a un servidor remoto con el servicio "mongod" activo. He estado consultando por ahí, y todos los sitios encuentro lo mismo:

-Configuración en `/etc/mongo.conf` sobre "bindIp", etc.

El caso es que yo introduzco el uri de conexión mediante mongoose a la hora de conectar y lo hago mediante: `mongodb://user:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/db`.
Realmente no se que configuraciones debería de hacer antes, si estaría mejor conectar mediante un tunel SSH o como. Pero se me han acabado las ideas.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: te conectas local?

Comment: No, me conecto a un servidor remoto.

Comment: pero intentastees conectarte local, inicia el servicio con`systemctl start mongod`

Comment: El servicio está iniciado, y en local se conecta perfectamente. ¿Podría ser por los puertos? En concreto el 27017. He habilitado unas reglas para abrir el puerto y tampoco hay cambios. En el archivo de configuración de mongodb en el apartado net: bindIp: está puesto el valor 0.0.0.0 para aceptar todas las ip´s.

Comment: A ver, que me cuesta entender. Tratas de conectarte desde Mongoose (imagino que una aplicacion sobre NodeJS) a una `uri` remota (es decir otro servidor donde está la base de datos de Mongo, puerto estándar). El error que te da al intentar la conexión es `ETIMEDOUT`. Mi duda es, ¿qué tiene que ver el archivo `/etc/mongod.conf` en todo esto? ¿Acaso el servicio `mongod` no está activo en el equipo remoto? Por otro lado, como comenta @JackNavaRow, ¿has probado abrir una consola de Mongo en el equipo remoto (suponiendo que tienes acceso al mismo)?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿sabes si el equipo remoto tiene habilitado el envío de paquetes a través del puerto 27017? Tal vez falte una configuración en `iptables` o en el firewall, según sea el caso. Prueba cambiando las opciones de conexión, puedes pasarle parámetros como `connectTimeoutMS: 15000,  reconnectInterval: 800,  reconnectTries: 5` o los valores que tu creas convenientes.

Comment: Si, el servicio mongod está activo en el equipo remoto. En cuanto a lo del archivo de configuración de mongo: "mongod.conf", su opción bindIp, hasta donde yo he entendido, es para especificar las IPs por las que mongod o mongos va a escuchar conexiones de clientes. Creo que la solución va a ser abrir el puerto 27017 como comentas. El equipo remoto utiliza Centos 6.10.

Comment: Exacto, `bindIP` se utiliza para permitir que mongo escuche peticiones en las interfaces que le añadas. Si colocas `0.0.0.0` estarías indicando que escuche en todas las interfaces disponibles usando IPv4. Por lo tanto, si la conexión local funciona, debes revisar el enrutamiento de puertos, ya sea en el sistema operativo y también en el router (si es el caso). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como indicas que puedes conectar de forma local solo quedaria que intentases hacer telnet desde el servidor remoto al puerto 27017, si el telnet no funciona quizas sea un problema de iptables o de firewalld:

Despues de verificar si puedes o no conectar por telnet que lo mas probable es que no, miraria de crear la regla en iptables si las tienes activadas:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

Otra cosa que podria pasar si has estado modificando el paramtro binIP es que alguna informacion se hubiera quedado guardada en el socket de la bbdd por lo que quizas fuera conveniente para la bbdd y borrar el socket:

```
rm /etc/mongodb-XXXXX.sock
```